# My application tries replace another my application

Tags: android

My application tries replace another my application.

I add aplication on git https://github.com/szalek/AndroidLevel1.

When I install the application 'Vinyl' and next install the application 'TeamLeader1/'. 
I see message 'The application you are installing will replace another application. All previous user data will be saved'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because both applications have the same package name. If the package name of the two applications are different, you won't get this message.

In fact, if the package name in the Manifest file (in the `<manifest>` tag) matches the package name of another installed application, it will replace it.

Comment: Note that since the addition of the Gradle building system replacing the package name in the manifest doesn't solve the issue. It is necessary to also replace it in the build.gradle file associated to the app module. The package name should be associated to the key `applicationId`.