# Replace a system application with your own modified application on android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I downloaded the source code of OI Notepad and did some modifications to it. And then made an .apk file out of it. But when I try to install the .apk it shows

```
This is a system application.
Do you still want to replace it?
```

When i say yes it moves forward but does not install it..
I have this post [My application tries replace another my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621723/my-application-tries-replace-another-my-application) and the answer given there the package name of both the apps cannot be same. 
But is there any way in which I can manage to install modified OI Notepad without any hassles of replacing the older one. It happens in Emulator..
Thanks

Comment: Yes change the package="" tag that is in your manifest.

Comment: Just for clarification..Will that be enough to make it different from the parent project? By not changing anything in source files, android differentiates between two application, just on the basis of Manifest file only. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using eclipse you can right click the package tree and use the refactor option to quickly change the package. This, in most cases, correctly updates the Application Manifest for you. This 'should' resolve the error you are having keeping in mind that you will now have two versions of the application so it may be in your best interest to change the application name of your custom version so you can easily distinguish between the two.

Comment: Did that once, forgot it, Will do it again